# How to call a Scriptblock as a function parameter in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell, scriptblock

I would like to have a function to run different **ScriptBlock**s. So, I need to use my Scriptblock as the parameter of the function. It does not work.

For example. This function returns the ScriptBlock as a string.

```
function Run_Scriptblock($SB) {
    return $SB
}
```

These are the outputs from my tries:

```
# 1st try
Run_Scriptblock {systeminfo}

>> systeminfo


# 2nd try
Run_Scriptblock systeminfo

>> systeminfo


# 3rd try
Run_Scriptblock [scriptblock]systeminfo

>> [scriptblock]systeminfo


# 4th try
$Command = [scriptblock]{systeminfo}
Run_Scriptblock $Command

>> [scriptblock]systeminfo


# 5th try
[scriptblock]$Command = {systeminfo}
Run_Scriptblock $Command

>> systeminfo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a function to *run* a scriptblock, you need to actually *invoke* or *call* that scriptblock, i.e.

```
function Run_Scriptblock($SB) {
    $SB.Invoke()
}
```

or

```
function Run_Scriptblock($SB) {
    & $SB
}
```

Otherwise the function will just return the scriptblock definition in string form. The `return` keyword is not needed, since PowerShell functions [return all non-captured output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-3.0) by default.

The function would be called like this:

```
Run_Scriptblock {systeminfo}
```

---

As a side note, I would recommend you consider naming your function following PowerShell conventions (`<Verb>-<Noun>` with an [approved verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands)), e.g.

```
function Invoke-Scriptblock($SB) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd also add the cmdlet 'invoke-expression' to this list too.

Comment: @M2065 [I wouldn't](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/), and neither should you.